# Error en código PL/SQL

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, plsql

estoy empezando con `PL/SQL` y me han surgido algunos errores que no entiendo, alguien puede ayudarme a saber que estoy haciendo mal.

Error 1:

> Error(2,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting
>   one of the following:     ( ; is with authid as cluster compress order
>   using compiled    wrapped external deterministic parallel_enable
>   pipelined    result_cache

Error 2:

> Error(24,4): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when
>   expecting one of the following:     ( begin case declare end exception
>   exit for goto if loop mod    null pragma raise return select update
>   while with     
>    << continue close current delete fetch lock
>   insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall    merge
>   pipe purge

Este es el código:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE listado  
DECLARE      
  nom USUARIOS.nombre%TYPE;      
  cant number;      
  contador NUMBER := 0;

  CURSOR c_lista(cod USUARIOS.DNI%TYPE) IS  
     SELECT nombre, COUNT (*) AS CANTIDAD   
     FROM USUARIOS, MOVIMIENTOS     
     WHERE USUARIOS.DNI = MOVIMIENTOS.DNI AND       
           id_rol = '03'    
     GROUP BY nombre    
     ORDER BY CANTIDAD DESC; 

BEGIN    
  OPEN c_lista('DNI');      
  LOOP 
    FETCH c_lista INTO nom, cant;
    contador:= contador+1;
    EXIT WHEN c_lista%NOTFOUND OR contador <5;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(nom||': '||cant);      
  END LOOP;     
  CLOSE c_lista;

END; 
/
```

Comment: Debe quitar el `DECLARE` y recomiendo que recorra el cursor con un `FOR`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay algunos detalles que deben ser corregidos en el código.

**La sintaxis**

Según la [documentación de Oracle /PLSQL](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/procedures.php) la sintaxis de creación de un procedure es el siguiente:

```
CREATE [OR REPLACE] PROCEDURE procedure_name
    [ (parameter [,parameter]) ]

IS
    [declaration_section]

BEGIN
    executable_section

[EXCEPTION
    exception_section]

END [procedure_name];
```

Viendo esto, le faltó el  **`IS`** después de la declaración del nombre de tu procedimiento.

**Tipo de cursor**

En oracle se puede abrir un cursor de dos maneras:

- **Explícita:** Que es la forma que utilizaste.
- **Implícita:** Para mi esta forma es más sencilla, se utiliza el ciclo for para acceder a los resultados de la consulta.

Utilizando el acceso implícito al cursor, el código quedaría de la siguiente manera.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE listado  IS

  contador NUMBER := 0;

  CURSOR c_lista(cod USUARIOS.DNI%TYPE) IS  
     SELECT nombre, COUNT (*) AS CANTIDAD   
     FROM USUARIOS, MOVIMIENTOS     
     WHERE USUARIOS.DNI = MOVIMIENTOS.DNI AND       
     id_rol = '03'    
     GROUP BY nombre    
     ORDER BY CANTIDAD DESC; 

BEGIN    

  FOR r IN c_lista LOOP
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(r.nom||': '||r.cant);
     contador := contador + 1;
  END LOOP;

END listado; 
/
```

Si deseas cortar el recorrido del loop antes de que finalice el ciclo podes usar también el comando **`EXIT`**.

```
  FOR r IN c_lista LOOP
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(r.nom||': '||r.cant);
     contador := contador + 1;

     EXIT WHEN contador < 5;
  END LOOP;
```

Comment: Mil gracias! Ya me funcionó. Saludos!

Comment: gracias! me sirvió tu explicación!